# Can I go further for this problem? If $f(x) = f'(x) + \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$ find $f((a+b)/2)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f :(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable for all $x\in(0,1)$ and satifies \begin{equation} f(x) = f'(x) + \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx\tag{1}\end{equation} for all $x\in (0,1)$. If there exist $a,b\in(0,1)$ such that $f(a) = f(b) = (a + b)/2$, determine the value of $f((a + b)/2)$.

**My Approach**

Let $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) dx = S$. Since $f$ is differentiable(and hence continue) we have a differential equation $$f'(x) - f(x) = -S$$ whose  homogenous solution is $f_h(x) = ce^x$ for some constant $c$. Since the particular solution is $f_p(x) = S$, it follows that $c =0$. From this we conclude that the solution is  $f(x) = S$ for all $x\in (0,1)$. In other word, $f(x)$ is constant for $x\in (0,1)$ and hence $$f((a + b)/2) =f(a) = f(b) = (a + b)/2.$$
Is this correct? Am I on the right track? I'm not really sure about my answer though. I think we can get further or maybe there is another approach to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conclusion is right, but for the wrong reasons. 
The solution to your equation is $$f(x)=ce^x+S$$(you can check directly that $f(x)-f'(x)=-S$). But now you can go back to your original equation, and you have 
$$\tag1
ce^x+S=ce^x+\int_0^1(ce^x+S)\,dx=ce^x+c(e-1)+S.
$$
From $(1)$ now you deduce that $c(e-1)=0$, so $c=0$.

Finally, you now know that $f$ is constant, so
$$
f(x)=f(a)=\frac{a+b}2
$$
for all $x$; in particular, for $x=\frac{a+b}2$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So it's indeed that is the furthest we tell about $f((a + b)/2)$?

Comment: You can tell that $f((a+b)/2)=(a+b)/2$. Not sure what else you want to say.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on the right track.

The given differential equation   $$\begin{equation} f(x) = f'(x) + \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx\tag{1}\end{equation}$$has a solution $$\begin{equation} f(x) = ce^x+ \int_0^1 f(x) \,dx\tag{1}\end{equation}$$The condition $$f(a) = f(b)$$ implies that $$ce^a=ce^b$$Therefore either $c=0$ or $a=b$.

If $c=0$ the function is constant and $ f(\frac {a+b}{2})=f(a)=  \frac {a+b}{2}$

If $ c\ne 0 $ then $a=b=\frac {a+b}{2}$ therefore $ f(\frac {a+b}{2})=f(a)=  \frac {a+b}{2}$